# Change default search box text

Tags: 2013, search, search-box

How can I change the default text in the site search box?

I know how to do this with a search box web part but am having trouble changing the site search box. I tried changing the two control display templates in the search folder but that didn't work. I also looked through the master page and didn't find anything.

I can change the value after the page loads via `jQuery`, but by doing that I physically change the value and the existing script gets messed up. For example, if I were to use the drop down to search for 'People', when I click it it will run the search because my new value is inserted by the script.

Is there somewhere that I'm missing to go and change the default title and/or value of that search box?

Comment: If you are working on your local machine then, [try this](http://blogs.c5insight.com/Home/tabid/40/entryid/290/Quick-Tip-Change-the-Search-this-site-text-in-SharePoint-2010.aspx) and update me if it's working or not

Comment: For SharePoint online, you can use PowerShell to achieve this as explained in article: https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2021/06/20/sharepoint-online-how-to-change-the-placeholder-text-in-the-search-box/

Answer (score 2):

Modifying the display templates is the only option

1. Open Display Templates -> Search
2. Edit file `Control_SearchBox`
3. Replace the value for the promt variable with the text that you want to display.

[image]

4. Save the file. (If required publish and approve)

[image]

Source - http://blogs.technet.com/b/tothesharepoint/archive/2013/09/19/how-to-change-the-text-that-is-displayed-in-the-search-box-web-part-in-sharepoint-server-2013.aspx

Comment: I tried this.  `"I tried changing the two control display templates in the search folder but that didn't work."`  Is there another place that the default site search box is being used in?

Comment: From what I can gather is that the above solution only works if you are inserting a search box web part and using that display template.

Comment: In the display template, remove the `if($isNull..` condition and set the text in all cases. Try that and let me know.

Comment: Taking the condition out didn't fix it either.  I added in the actual search box web part to make sure the changes were occurring at all and they are working for the inserted web part.

Comment: In the display templates folder can you see a file with name `Control_SearchBox_Compact.js`? If you can then change the text inside that file also.

Comment: That is the other display template I was referring to before as well.  I just tried taking out the condition in that one without success.

Comment: Strange. Are you on-premise. Then try opening `C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\TEMPLATE\FEATURES\OSearchBasicFeature\SearchArea.xml` and add a new node `<Property Name="InitialPrompt">New Search Prompt</Property>`