# Change the default “search this site” text for SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-server, search, site, input

Good day,

I would like to change “search this site” text for my SharePoint Search field to "Search...". I open my master page and add the script

```
        <script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[                

          $(document).ready(function()
            {        

        $('input.ms-helperText').attr('value', "Search... ");
        $('input.ms-helperText').attr('title', "Search... ");
        $('input.ms-helperText').click(function() { 
        $('input.ms-helperText').attr('value', "");
            });




        //]]>
        </script>
```

It works fine for Google Chrome and Firefox, but it doesn't work for IE. Even for IE11. I can't understand, why.

This solution didn't help too https://radhikakasetty.wordpress.com/2011/09/12/change-the-search-this-site-text-of-the-search-box-sharepoint-2010/

I would be grateful for any info.

Answer (score 0):

Per my test, your script doesn't work in Chrome.  F12(developer tools) console shows this error:

[image]

You need to add  }); in the end of your code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[                

          $(document).ready(function()
            {        

        $('input.ms-helperText').attr('value', "Search... ");
        $('input.ms-helperText').attr('title', "Search... ");
        $('input.ms-helperText').click(function() { 
        $('input.ms-helperText').attr('value', "");
            });



        });
        //]]>
        </script>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, I didn't forget about  }); on my master page. I forgot to add them here. Script didn't work in IE.

Comment: When I view Site Page in IE, I see the js, which defined “search this site” text for my SharePoint Search field. This Script

Comment: ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(
                        function() 
                        {
                            if ($isNull($find('ctl00_PlaceHolderSearchArea_SmallSearchInputBox1_csr')))
                            {
                                var sb = $create(Srch.SearchBox, {"delayLoadTemplateScripts":true,"initialPrompt":"SEARCH THIS SITE","messages":[],"navigationNodes": ~sitecollection/_catalogs/masterpage/Display Templates/Search/Control_SearchBox_Compact.js"...));
                                
                            }
                        }

Comment: I tried to change Control_SearchBox_Compact and Control_SearchBox like here? but it didn't help https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/126241/change-default-search-box-text

Comment: I can't find the link to the script which set "SEARCH THIS SITE" text on master page...

Comment: What's the user permission when viewing pages in IE? Did you use the account with read permission? If so, you need to publish your master page after adding the script.

Comment: I use Site Owner account. I publish master page after every modifications.

Comment: I use: _spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("changefinditem");
     function changefinditem() {     document.getElementById("ctl00_PlaceHolderSearchArea_SmallSearchInputBox1_csr_sbox").value = "search...";         
       }   But I can't fix the problem. The text "Search..." doesn't disappear when I input search request